# get state's url data into templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
  .state('app.track', {
    url: "/tracks/:trackId",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/track.html",
        controller: 'TrackCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
```

in track.html I try `{{trackId}}` nothing is shown? But when I navigate I did see my trackId like tracks/abc in my browser URL. And what does app.track really means here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at  [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/).

app.track is the state and you cannot directly access the :tackId .You need to assign its value from controller to view with the help of $stateParams.

```
$scope.tackId=$stateParams.trackId
```

Comment: I alrdy got the trackId, how to pass that to my view? track.html?

Comment: controller: 'TrackCtrl'

Comment: I got it .controller('TrackCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.id= $stateParams.trackId;
});